# Android : How can I open a file using OpenCV C++ ?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I have a video file saved on my Android device.

Using a `getPath()` function I got "sdcard/video_app/sample_video.mp4".

I'm now trying to use this video file in my OpenCV C++ code (I'm using NDK and JNI) with this :

```
String filename = "sdcard/video_app/sample_video.mp4";

VideoCapture capture(filename);

Mat img;

capture >> img;

imwrite("sdcard/video_app/test.jpg", img);
```

I added :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Nothing is happening. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: only MJPG codec in an avi container is supported from opencv

Comment: I've tried this code with a MJPEG video in an avi container, it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can try,

```
VideoCapture capture=new VideoCapture();
capture.open("sdcard/video_app/sample_video.mp4");
Mat frames = new Mat();

 // to read each frame and to save in Mat class           
for(;;)
{
   capture.read(frames); 
   imwrite("sdcard/video_app/test.jpg",frame);
}
```